# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entity

I want to get some fields and then set it to my Test.entity. My SQL query:

```
                query = "SELECT t.id as tId, t.test_name, t.duration, q.id as qId, " +
                    "q.question as question, q.is_multichoice as is_multichoice, " +
                    "q.is_open as is_open, a.id as aId, a.answer_text as answer_text  FROM result r " +
                    "JOIN test t ON r.test_id = t.id " +
                    "JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.id " +
                    "JOIN question q ON t.id = q.test_id JOIN answer a ON q.id = a.question_id " +
                    "WHERE t.id = :testId AND u.id = :userId AND r.permission = :permissionId " +
                    "AND q.archived = false AND a.archived = false", resultClass = com.bionic.entities.Test.class)
```

**Test Entity:**

```
public class Test {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Column(name = "duration", nullable = false)
private int duration;
@Column(name = "test_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String testName;
@Column(name = "archived", nullable = false)
private boolean archived;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "test", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Question> questions;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tests")
private Set<User> users;
```

**Question Entity**:

```
public class Question {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Column(name = "is_multichoice", nullable = false)
private boolean isMultichoice;
@Column(name = "is_open", nullable = false)
private boolean isOpen;
@Column(name = "picture")
private String picture;
@Column(name = "question")
private String question;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "test_id", nullable = false)
private Test test;
@Column(name = "archived", nullable = false)
private boolean isArchived;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Answer> answers;
```

Answer Entity:

```
public class Answer {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
@Column(name = "answer_text", nullable = false)
private String answerText;
@Column(name = "mark", nullable = false)
private int mark;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
private Question question;
@Column(name = "picture")
private String picture;
@Column(name = "archived", nullable = false)
private boolean isArchived;
```

However, after executing this query i am getting exeption :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
```

**DAO.class:**

```
    public Test getCurrentTest(long id, long testId, long permissionId) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("getCurrentTestById");
    query.setParameter("userId", id);
    query.setParameter("testId", testId);
    query.setParameter("permissionId", permissionId);
    return (Test) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please make sure that all your table has got column named __id__

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query doesn't return a field named `id`. It has fields named `aId, qId, and tId`.

You need to use the correct column names in your entities. For example, in your Test entity, you declared a column named id. Except your query doesn't return a column named id, it returns a column named tId. See below for an example of what needs to be changed.

```
public class Test {
@tId
@Column(name = "tId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long tId;
 ....
```

Comment: how could i map it to my id filed in entity?

Comment: I mean that i have 3 fields called id (test, question, aswer), but i can't get by SQL query 3 fields with same name "id"

Comment: I understand that. And that's why you gave those 3 fields an alias. Thereby changing the name of the fields so they are unique. But that also means your code doesn't see a field named id. You need to reference the field by its new alias.

Comment: should i use SqlResultSetMappings for that or rename fields in each entity (this variant i don't like)
if i should use SqlResultSetMappings, how could i set fields for answers and questions as they are subenteties

Comment: You need to use the correct column names in your entities. For example, in your Test entity, you declared a column named `id`. Except your query doesn't return a column named `id`, it returns a column named `tId`.

Comment: How can i set tId to test id?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Your references are ambiguous. I edited the post with more info, hopefully that will clear some things up for you.

Comment: ah, you mean i should call them in db like that